# Stylized tool tips using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, tooltip

A while ago I used the code at the link http://www.jquerybyexample.net/2012/09/tutorial-for-creating-simple-stylized-tooltip-using-jquery.html to create a tool tip that follows the mouse when hovering over a widget that is tool tip enabled.  This was before HTML5 really came out which supports tool tips, but not quite in the way I want.

Anyway, the code has the x and y offsets from the mouse hard coded, such that the x-offset is 20 pixels to the right and the y-offset is 10 pixels up from the mouse, and follows the mouse over the widget. This is usually OK, but when the widget is near the right of the window this can be a problem.  Of course although I can hard code any values, I want to be able to specify the offsets in the HTML code.

I'm in the process of updating my website and putting it on a new server.  The original page is still at the link http://cs-cubed.com:8080/ and makes use of this feature (to avoid a port collision this is now on port 8080).  You can mouse over the items below the green line to see this.  The green hit counter is not working and this page is no longer being maintained.

The new page is at the link https://cs-cubed.com/ (note that an SSL certificate has not been installed yet) makes use of the modified jQuery code:

```
$(function() {
  $('.tool-tip').hover(function(event) {
    var toolTip = $(this).attr('tlp');
    var offy = $(this).attr('offy');             // Line added
    var offx = $(this).attr('offx');             // Line added
    if (typeof offy === 'undefined') offy = -10; // If no offset is given use this default
    if (typeof offx === 'undefined') offx = 20;  // If no offset is given use this default
    $('<span class="tooltip"></span>').text(toolTip)
      .appendTo('body')
      .css('top', (event.pageY + offy) + 'px')   // Replace the hard code by offy
      .css('left', (event.pageX + offx) + 'px')  // Replace the hard code by offx
      .fadeIn('slow');
   }, function() {
      $('.tooltip').remove();
   }).mousemove(function(event) {
     $('.tooltip')
       .css('top', (event.pageY + offy) + 'px')  // Replace the hard code by offy
       .css('left', (event.pageX + offx) + 'px');// Replace the hard code by offx
  });
});
```

Then for e.g. for the tool tip for the "Update Log" button on the lower right in the new page I have the following HTML code:

```
<div class="box j">
  <input id="update-log" class="btn tool-tip" tlp="Click on this button to see the update log. If the last
    update in the log does not match the date at the bottom here, you may need to refresh your browser by
    entering cs-cubed.com/update-log.html and refrshing the browser."
    type="button" value="Update Log" />
</div>
```

using the modified jQuery code.  This still works as long as I don't add offx and offy as attributes in the HTML code, so these are undefined in the jQuery code and the defaults are used.  However the tool tip does not follow the mouse when it moves over the widget.

Much more serious is that attempts to include the attributes offx and/or offy in the HTML code do not work.  For e.g. I want something like:

```
<div class="box j">
  <input id="update-log" class="btn tool-tip" offx="-20" offy="5" tlp="Click on this ..."
    type="button" value="Update Log" />
</div>
```

for the tool tip for the button, with offsets specified as offx and offy attributes, but either nothing is displayed, or the tool tip appears in a completely different part of the page.

All the research I've done online has failed to find a solution to this, and would most appreciate finding out how to fix this problem. It must be related to the fact that with the modified jQuery code the tool tip does not follow the mouse over the widget when the offsets are left blank.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the offset values retrieval in your `mousemove()` function callback

```
.mousemove(function(event) {
    var offy = $(this).attr('offy');
    var offx = $(this).attr('offx');

    if (typeof offy === 'undefined') offy = -10;  // If offy isn't given use this default

    if (typeof offx === 'undefined') offx = 20;   // If offx isn't given use this default

    $('.tooltip')
        .css('top', (event.pageY + offy) + 'px')
        .css('left', (event.pageX + offx) + 'px');
});
```

**UPDATE**

It's nothing but one of quirks of JS, since the attributes themselves are string like `offy="20"` so when you do `event.pageY + offy` it takes it as '720' + '20' = '72020'. What you need it is to convert the attribute value to a number then use it like so

```
$('.tool-tip').hover(function(event) {
       var toolTip = $(this).attr('tlp');
       var offy = $(this).attr('offy');
       offy = parseInt(offy);
       var offx = $(this).attr('offx');
       offx = parseInt(offx);

       //...

    }, function() {
        $('.tooltip').remove();
    }).mousemove(function(event) {
       var offy = $(this).attr('offy');
       offy = parseInt(offy);
       var offx = $(this).attr('offx');
       offx = parseInt(offx);

       //...

});
```

Comment: I've added the code you suggested in the mousemove() function, and it makes the tool tip follow the mouse when hovering over a link, but if I place offy and offx attributes in the HTML code, it doesn't work for that widget.  I inserted offy="20" offx="-10" before tlp="Click on this button..." for the blue "Update Log" button, and when you hover over that button the scroll bar on the right behaves as if something is added to the page well below, but nothing is displayed.  The other widgets without offsets work OK.  I've uploaded the code to https://cs-cubed.com/ and you can look at the source.

Answer (score 0):

OK, many thanks indeed, after some additional fiddling around I got it to work. The full code is as follows:

```
$('.tool-tip').hover(function(event) {
  var toolTip = $(this).attr('tlp');
  var offy = $(this).attr('offy');
  var offx = $(this).attr('offx');
  offy = (typeof offy === 'undefined') ? -10 : parseInt(offy);  // If offy isn't given use this default
  offx = (typeof offx === 'undefined') ?  20 : parseInt(offx);  // If offx isn't given use this default
  $('<span class="tooltip"></span>').text(toolTip)
    .appendTo('body')
    .css('top', (event.pageY + offy) + 'px')
    .css('left', (event.pageX + offx) + 'px')
    .fadeIn('slow');
}, function() {
  $('.tooltip').remove();
}).mousemove(function(event) {
  var offy = $(this).attr('offy');
  var offx = $(this).attr('offx');
  offy = (typeof offy === 'undefined') ? -10 : parseInt(offy); // If offy isn't given use this default
  offx = (typeof offx === 'undefined') ?  20 : parseInt(offx); // If offx isn't given use this default
  $('.tooltip')
    .css('top', (event.pageY + offy) + 'px')
    .css('left', (event.pageX + offx) + 'px');
});
```

where I have tidied up the code by using the tertiary operator.

However, there is trap you have to look out for. At no time can the tool tip cover over where the mouse is pointing, otherwise it won't be displayed. This explains why the default values of the x- and y-offsets in the original code are 20 and -10 respectively, so that the top left corner of the tool tip window is to the right and slightly above where the mouse is pointing, such that the first line of the tool tip text is level horizontally with the mouse. Normally this is OK except if the widget is near the right side of the browser's window, which gave me the problems mentioned earlier.

If the x-offset is set to zero or a negative value, the tool tip risks running over where the mouse is pointing. If at the same time the y-offset is set to a negative value such that the tool tip window's upper left corner is well above the widget, the tool tip may stay clear of running over the position of the mouse, but if there is not enough space between the mouse and the right of the browser's window, the text in the tool tip spills over several lines and can cause the bottom of the tool tip to run over where the mouse is pointing.  Either a large negative y-offset should be used to avoid this, or preferably use a large enough positive y-offset. In the latter case as the tool tip's window increases downwards if its text spills over more lines it will stay clear of the mouse.

Obviously when setting up a page using such tool tips, care must be made to ensure that these problems are avoided. Unless there is some code that can calculate where to place the tool tips.  I plan to upload the modified code to the sever in due course.